# meta_key and meta_value not working together

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, meta-query

I am trying to filter the loop to find posts that have a `meta_key` with a specific `meta_value`. I've looked at the Codex, and I've tried the following with no luck:

```
// No results
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'cqpp_interventions',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'meta_key' => 'priority',
                /* Tried this too
                'meta_value' => '80',
                'compare' => '='
                */
                'meta_value' => array('80'),
                'compare' => 'IN' )
    )
);

// No results
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'cqpp_interventions',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'meta_key' => 'priority',
    'meta_value' => 80
);

// This list me all cqpp_interventions and I can confirm that I have some with meta_value set to 80
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'cqpp_interventions',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'meta_key' => 'priority'
);


$cqpp_posts = get_posts( $args );
```

Here is how I verify inside the loop:

```
$priority = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'priority');
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($priority);
echo '</pre>';
```

which results in:

```
search.php:16:
array (size=1)
    0 => 
        array (size=1)
            0 => string '80' (length=2)

search.php:16:
array (size=1)
    0 => 
        array (size=2)
        0 => string '80' (length=2)
        1 => string '91' (length=2)
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'cqpp_interventions',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'priority',
            'value' => '80'
        )
    )
);
```

The real issue with your query is because you are passing `meta_key` and `meta_value`. However, the arrays in your `meta_query` argument should have the keys `key` and `value` instead.

This would also work:

```
'key' => 'priority',
'value' => array('80')
```

Answer (score 0):

From the reference of your first $args

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'cqpp_interventions',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'meta_key' => 'priority',
                /* Tried this too
                'meta_value' => '80',
                'compare' => '='
                */
                'meta_value' => array('80'),
                'compare' => 'IN' )
    )
);
```

You have added `'relation' => 'OR'`, which is not needed. The `relation` needs to be added if you have multiple meta-value to be queried. Also compare is not needed if you want a specific value, as by default is uses `=`.

The updated $args will be

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'cqpp_interventions',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'meta_key' => 'priority',
                'meta_value' => '80', // since 80 is string
             )
    )
);

// try either of below.
$myPost = new WP_Query( $args ); // fetch post and managed in objects
$myPost = get_posts( $args ); // fetch post and store in array
```

Hope this will help you out.

Thanks

Comment: In meta_query you use 'key' => and  'value' => not use 'meta_key' => and 'meta_value' => like Chin Leung answer